# How to get AzureKeyVault Secret without storing the ClientSecret in appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, azure, winforms, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

How to get AzureKeyVault Secret without storing the ClientSecret in appsettings.json? We have a WinForms application in .NET 5 using Dependency Injection and we want to add two services to the ServiceProvider while only requiring one SSO login prompt *and* removing the KeyVault secret string from the appsettings.json file.

The call to `builder.AddAzureKeyVault(SecretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager())` works when signed in to Azure with Visual Studio. This breaks when we deploy the application for a virtual machine where Visual Studio is not signed in. We can get this to work by passing in a `secret` value, but we don't want to store that in either code or appsettings. How do we store the `secret` in the KeyVault and then retrieve that so that we can add the `AddAzureKeyVault` service?

When we log out of Visual Studio (i.e., `ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true`) then we get the following error:

> Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: 'DefaultAzureCredential
> failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
>
> - EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
> - ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No Managed Identity endpoint found.
> - Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\gwrwzu2y.rwb\TokenService\Microsoft.Asal.TokenService.exe"
>   has failed with unexpected error: TS003: Error, TS005: No accounts
>   found.  Please go to Tools->Options->Azure Services Authentication,
>   and add an account to be to authenticate to Azure services during
>   development..
> - Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account.
> - Azure CLI not installed
> - Please run 'Connect-AzAccount' to set up account.'

Note 1: We are using SSO and can retrieve the AccessToken. So, we have access to the AccessToken.

Note 2: we are using `SlowCheetah` for multiple environment configs, so we do not have ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES setup.

From Program.cs

```
Static Void Main()
{
...
Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {
        builder.SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            ;

        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            ;

        // Set the Configuration. We need to build the Configuration here so that we can get access to the Appsettings in order to
        // set the SecretClient and add the Azure Key Vault. We will then need to set the Configuration again in order to capture this
        // new service.
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        SetSecretClient(Configuration);

        // Add the Azure Key Vault. This only works when signed into Azure via Visual Studio
        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(SecretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        Configuration = context.Configuration;

        SignInUserSSO();

        ConfigureServices(Configuration, services);
    })
    .Build();
...
}

private static void SetSecretClient(IConfiguration objConfiguration)
{
    DefaultAzureCredentialOptions objDefaultAzureCredentialOptions;
    SecretClientOptions objSecretClientOptions;

    string strAzureKeyVaultResourceIdentifier = objConfiguration.GetValue<string>("Azure:FirmId:ResourceIdentifiers:KeyVault");
    string strAzureKeyVaultName = objConfiguration.GetValue<string>("Azure:FirmId:KeyVaults:NameOfKeyVault");
    string strAzureKeyVaultUri = strAzureKeyVaultResourceIdentifier.Replace("{KeyVaultName}", strAzureKeyVaultName);

    // Set the options on the SecretClient. These are default values recommended by Microsoft.
    objSecretClientOptions = new SecretClientOptions()
    {
        Retry =
        {
            Delay= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
            MaxRetries = 5,
            Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
            }
    };

    objDefaultAzureCredentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
        ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = false,
        ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
        ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true,
        ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
        ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
        ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true
    };

    SecretClient = new SecretClient(
        vaultUri: new Uri(strAzureKeyVaultUri),
        credential: new DefaultAzureCredential(objDefaultAzureCredentialOptions),
        objSecretClientOptions
        );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried by assigning a managed identity to the VM where you're running this application?

Comment: I don't think we can assign a Managed Identity to a VM. How would we do that?

Comment: Assuming your VM is running in Azure, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-sign-in.

Comment: The VM is in Azure. Does this require a code change to the above?

Comment: No, I don’t think so. What you would need to do though is to give proper permission to your managed identity to access your key vault.

Comment: Is it possible to grant access to the Managed Identity to my local dev computer so that I can test that it works?

Comment: Nope. Managed Identify is an Azure native concept. For local dev, you’ve 4 options: VS Credentials, VSCode Credentials. Azure PowerShell Credetand Azure CLI Credentials.

Comment: This looks promising. Can you please post an answer to it? Can you, perhaps, touch on what the optimal setup for security would be in Azure (your profile indicates you have a lot of experience with Azure)? Also, which Azure Powershell modules need to be installed to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DefaultAzureCredential](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/README.md#defaultazurecredential) uses a number of authentication methods to support both production and development environments without changing code. So while you can use your Visual Studio, Azure CLI, or other credentials during development, you can use environment variables with service principals or managed identity in production. For VMs, managed identity is probably the easiest to configure, and for services that don't support managed identity you can use environment variables configured on your service that are authorized to access your Key Vault.

FWIW, recommended default retry settings are already the default without specifying a `SecretClientOptions` instance if you want to simplify code.